# How to catch all exceptions that aren't already thrown by function?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, throw

I am a little doubtful this is possible, but getting more information about this would be very helpful. I am wondering how to catch all exceptions that a function doesn't already throw.

Say I have a function:

```
public int func(int a, int b) throws IOException, EOFException {
    try {
        doSomething(a, b);
    } catch (AllExceptionsExceptionIOandEOF e) {
        doSomethingWithError(e);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to tell Java how to do that? I know throwing the generic `Exception` works for all, but I want to throw all but the thrown exception.

If this is considered bad practice, why? And what is a good alternative to accomplish the same goal?

(PS -- I know, I know the adage that all possible exceptions need to be handled individually. For my purposes, I just want to catch the errors, log them in a database, and see what things are coming up that we missed during development. I am reluctant to catch the generic `Exception` when my function is already throwing 2 exceptions)

It just occured to me, one way would be to say:

```
try {
    doSomething(a, b);
} catch (AllExceptionsExceptionIOandEOF e) {
    doSomethingWithError(e);
    if (e instanceof IOException)
        throw e;
    if (e instanceof EOFException)
        throw e;
}
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this though?

EDIT - The project is done in Java 6 compliance, unfortunately. I know Java 7 has made Try/Catches a bit more flexible though.

Comment: Only do this in *one* place in your application. See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/effective-exceptions-092345.html

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    doSomething(a, b);
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw e;
} catch (EOFException e) {
    throw e;
} catch (Exception e){
    doSomethingWithError(e);
}
```

Comment: Ah not bad, though I hate repeating code. Voting up but hoping there is a more elegant way...

Comment: that is not good at all... catch exception is not a good practice.. if the doSomething don't throw Exception you don't want to catch Exception..

Answer (score 0):

From java 1.7 you can group exceptions behaviour.

```
try{
      //some code
}catch( IOException | AnotherException e){
  //do what you want
}catch(RuntimeException re){
    //happen a runtimexception 
}
```

And to catch all exceptions that function doesn't throw it only can be `RuntimeException` and subclasses cause they are unchecked exceptions.

And for hierachy exceptions, first the subclasses and then more general.

For example :

```
 catch(EOFException e){

 }catch(IOException e){

 }
```

By the way, only catch exception once.

Comment: Catching the generic `Exception` won't include `RuntimeException`s as well?

Comment: @EricS yes but is a bad practice.. you have to catch the less generic exception.. :) , you also with that idea catch Throwable that will catch error and exception, but has no sense..

Answer (score 0):

In pre java1.7

```
try{}
catch(FileNotFoundException e){}
catch(IOException e){}
catch(Exception e){
    //anything not handled in other catch clause
}
```

Just be sure to declare your catch clauses from more specific to less specific.

In java 1.7 you can do fancier things:

```
catch(IOException | EOFException e){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since EOFException extends IOException you can catch IOException and throw it as below

catch( IOException e){
  //do what you want
}

Answer (score 0):

Per the other answers, especially pre-Java 1.7, you don't have a really good answer. If this is going to be done in many places in your code, and you primarily want it for development, I might suggest creating a special handler:

```
class ExceptionHandler
{
  public static void handle(Throwable t, Class<? extends Exception> rethrowClasses...)
  {
    for (Class e : rethrowClasses)
    {
      if e.isInstance(t)
      {
         throw t;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your exception block:

```
try
{ ... }
catch (Exception e)
{
  ExceptionHandler.handle(e, IOException.class, EOFException.class);
  // other processing
}
```

That would re-throw the requested exceptions, and you have a vararg list of which exceptions to re-throw for each exception block. You can re-use that and only add one line to each exception block. You could adjust the logic as needed to log the non-handled exceptions, or whatever else is needed.

It's not great, but there just aren't a lot of good solutions to your problem.